# How to get sums like these in the form of the Cauchy Product?

Tags: summation, cauchy-product

I know that the question isn't very well-worded, please feel free to change it to something better.

I have this sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{k} a_lx^ll!a_{k-l}x^{k-l+1}(k-l)!\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

This is the result of convoluting a polynomial of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with itself, so we'd have $\int_{0}^{x} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-t)^n)dt$, which can be rewritten as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_la_{k-l}\int_{0}^{x}t^l{(x-t)}^{k-l}dt$ which evaluates to the sum above.

I would like to find a way to put in a form such that it can be written as a product of two sums, that is $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{j} b_{k}c_{j-k}$$

Most of it is able to be written in this form, where $b_k=a_kx^kk!$ and $c_{j-k}=a_{j-k}x^{j-k+1}(j-k)!$. However, I still have that $\frac{1}{(j+1)!}.$ What I want to know is if there's any way I could algebraically manipulate that so that it can completely be in the form I want.

Thank You.

Comment: Where did you come across this sum?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I didn't actually come across it. I edited the question and added some new information which hopefully answers your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood but this can be done as follows.

Start writing the series obtained convoluting as
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k} \left( a_{\ell}\ a_{k-\ell}\ \ell!\ (k-\ell)! \right) x^{k+1} $$

Note that this is a power series with coefficients $A_k = \dfrac{1}{(k+1)!} \sum_\limits{\ell=0}^{k} \left( a_{\ell}\ a_{k-\ell}\ \ell!\ (k-\ell)! \right)$.

We want to write $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} A_k\ x^{k+1} = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_\limits{\ell=0}^{k} b_l\ c_{k-l}\ x^k =  \left( \sum_\limits{m=0}^{\infty} b_m\ x^m \right) \left( \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} c_n\ x^n \right) $, which still also a power series with coefficients $P_k = \sum_\limits{\ell=0}^{k} b_l\ c_{k-l}$.

Since a power series uniquely determines a function, it follows that the coeffiecients of both must be equal. That is, $P_0 = 0$ and $ P_{k+1} = A_k $. Also, because $P_0 = b_0 c_0$ we have that $b_0 = 0$ or $c_0 = 0$. Without loss of generality suppose that $b_0 \neq 0$; then $c_0 = 0$.

We gonna write $c_n$ as a function of $a_k$ and $b_m$.

For $k = 0$
$$ A_0 = a_{0}^2 = P_1 = b_0 c_1 + b_1 c_0 = b_0 c_1 \implies c_1 = \frac{a_0^2}{b_0} $$

For $k = 1$
$$ A_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( a_{0} a_{1} + a_{1} a_{0} \right) = a_{0} a_{1} = P_2 = b_0 c_2 + b_1 c_1 + b_2 c_0 = b_0 c_2 + b_1 c_1\\
\implies c_2 = \frac{1}{b_0} \left( a_{0} a_{1} - b_1 c_1 \right) $$

For $k = 2$
$$ A_2 = \frac{1}{3} \left( 4 a_0 a_2 + a_1^2 \right) = P_3 = b_0 c_3 + b_1 c_2 + b_2 c_1\\
\implies c_3 = \frac{1}{b_0} \left( \frac{1}{3} \left( 4 a_0 a_2 + a_1^2 \right) - b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1 \right) $$

And so on... Hence
$$ c_{n+1} = \frac{1}{b_0} \left( A_n - \sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1} b_{\ell}\ c_{k-\ell} \right) $$

This means that $b_n$ is a sequence that we are free to determine as long as we choose $c_n$ as above. Thus we may choose a sequence which make its respective power series to have infinite radius of convergence to avoid any problem, say $b_m = \dfrac{1}{m!}$; so $\sum_\limits{m=0}^{\infty} b_i\ x^i = e^x$. We are done.

Comment: But how to ensure that the series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x^n$ converges in a suitable range?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco This is guaranteed by construction. The radius of convergence of $\left( \sum_\limits{m=0}^{\infty} b_m\ x^m \right) \left( \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} c_n\ x^n \right)$ is $\min\{R_b, R_c\} = \min\{\infty, R_c\} = R_c$ and $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} A_k\ x^{k+1} = \left( \sum_\limits{m=0}^{\infty} b_m\ x^m \right) \left( \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} c_n\ x^n \right)$. Since both sides are power series, their radius of convegence must be equal, that is $R_A = R_c$. Hence its convergence depends on the convergence of the initial series presented by the OP.

Comment: To write the equality $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n = \left( \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x^n \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x^n \right)$ in the first place seems to be cyclic deduction.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco This is what OP is trying to do. Also the sequence $a_n$ is already known.

Comment: You understood correctly. Apologies for not being able to word things well. Thank you for the insightful response.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean the possibilty is not ruled out that there exist $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$, $\{c_n\}$ such that $a_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n b_k c_{n - k} \ (n \in \mathbb{N})$, but that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x_0^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x_0^n$ converge but $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x_0^n$ diverges.

Comment: You are welcome, @Sam!

Comment: That's exactly what seems to be cyclic deduction because the convergence of two series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x_0^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x_0^n$ is pre-assumed to prove the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x_0^n$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Since $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x_0^n \neq 0$, the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x^n$ follows from the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x_0^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x_0^n$.

Comment: Writing the equality$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x_0^n = \left( \sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x_0^n \right) \left( \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x_0^n \right)$$ preassumes the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n x_0^n$, which is **not** implied by $a_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n b_k c_{n - k}$ and thus is not valid. That equality holds automatically given $a_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n b_k c_{n - k}$ only if they are all formal power series.

Comment: Well, @AlexFrancisco...I apologize for being unable to understand your concerns. The convergence was just preassumed so that we could investigate sufficient conditions for its validity. Notice that what was essentially done here was $f(x) = f(x) e^x e^{-x} = e^x ( f(x) e^{-x})$.

Answer (score 0):

Put plainly, you want to express the Integral Convolution of a given polynomial
with itself by means of the product of two polynomials to be determined.

Keeping general, that is unspecified, the coefficients $a_k$ of the auto-convolved polynomial, 
that would mean to be able to express
$$
{{l!\left( {k - l} \right)!} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!}} = {1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}} = f(l)g(k - l)
$$
which is not possible, since the binomial is not splittable in such a multiplicative way.
In fact, that would imply
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right) = f(l)\,g(k - l)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  k - l \cr}  \right) = f(l)\,f(k - l)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {n + m} \right)! = F(n)\,F(m) \cr} 
$$
which cannot be for every $n$ and $m$.

That means that it is not assured that the polynomial resulting from the convolution 
be *in general factorizable* , except from having the constant term null and thus allowing to separate
a $x$.

For example
$$
\int_0^x {\left( {1 + t} \right)\left( {1 + x - t} \right)dt}  = {{x^{\,3} } \over 6} + x^{\,2}  + x = x\left( {{{x^{\,2} } \over 6} + x + 1} \right)
$$

Comment: I see. ${1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}} = f(l)g(k - l)$ is what I was trying to find. Is there a more specific reason why it can't be split in such a way?

Comment: added some explanation